# Reference memory allocation technique

Tags: c++, reference, sizeof

I am confused with the size of reference
i have taken two example and compiled it

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ABC
{

    int &y;
    ABC(int a):y(a)
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
  std::cout <<sizeof(ABC)<<endl;  
  return 0;
}
```

o/p - 8

and when i am taking size of reference out side of class

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int y = 7;
    int &x = y;

    cout<<sizeof(x);
}
```

o/p - 4

please confirm why the size of reference differ in side of class or inside a function.

Comment: The reference is just a pointer (a number in essence), which requires only 4 bytes for your computer, a class definition includes the size of y, the constructor function, and  any other definitions you might have. In short, they cannot be compared.

Answer (score 1):

> why the size of reference differ in side of class or inside a function.

Because the object calculated by `sizeof` is different. For `sizeof(x)`, [sizeof operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) will return the size of the referenced type, i.e. `int`.

> When applied to a reference type, the result is the size of the referenced type.

And `sizeof(ABC)` will return the size of class `ABC` which contains a reference. They're not the same thing.

Note that for the case about class containing refrence, the standard does not say about how reference should be implemented and what should be the size for the representation, but in most implementation reference will be implemented as a pointer, and on 64-bit systems, addresses are 64 bits so you might get the result of `8`.